# How to set prevState of a particular element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the user clicks on the eye icon of the new password, the user can only toggle(show or hide) the view of the new password field. Problem is it's toggling view for both new passwords and confirm password. How to toggle the eye icon view between a particular field only not for both fields.

```html
export default class ResetPassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      secure: true,
      newPassword: '',
      confirmPassword: ''
    }
  }


  togglePassword = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ secure: !prevState.secure }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <CommonBackground
          heading='Reset' />
        <Field
          label='New password'
          placeholder='Enter new password'
          secure={this.state.secure}
          icon
          onChangeText={newPassword => this.setState({ newPassword })}
          value={this.state.newPassword}
          action={this.togglePassword} />
        <Field
          label='Confirm password'
          placeholder='Enter password again'
          secure={this.state.secure}
          icon
          onChangeText={confirmPassword => this.setState({ confirmPassword })}
          value={this.state.confirmPassword}
          action={this.togglePassword} />
        
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
ResetPassword.navigationOptions = {
  header: null
}

export const Field = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  onChangeText,
  secure,
  icon,
  value,
  action
}) => (
  <View style={styles.fieldWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.heading}>{label}</Text>
    <View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={secure}
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value} />
      {icon ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={action}
          underlayColor='transparent'>
          {!secure ? <EyeView height={30} width={30} /> : <EyeHide height={30} width={30} />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: use different state variable for bot fields, this will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But don't want to create states and function for every field. Can you tell me how can I use an event object with the prevstate?

Comment: see the example - you have a switch and 4 bulbs, these bulbs are connected through  1 switch - if we on the switch, 4 bulbs will light. the same is happening here, you have single variable and 2 fields, if you change the variable - 2 fields will be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      passwordSecure: true,
      confirmPasswordSecure: true,
      newPassword: '',
      confirmPassword: ''
    }
  }

  
  togglePassword = (secure) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ [secure]: !prevState[secure] }))
  }

  render(){
   
    return(
    
      <div>      
        <Field
          label='New password'
          placeholder='Enter new password'
          secure={this.state.passwordSecure}
          icon
          onChangeText={newPassword => this.setState({ newPassword })}
          value={this.state.newPassword}
          action={() => this.togglePassword('passwordSecure')}
          type='newPassword' />
        <Field
          label='Confirm password'
          placeholder='Enter password again'
          type='newPassword'
          secure={this.state.confirmPasswordSecure}
          icon
          onChangeText={confirmPassword => this.setState({ confirmPassword })}
          value={this.state.confirmPassword}
          action={() => this.togglePassword('confirmPasswordSecure')} />
     </div>
     
    )
  }
}

export const Field = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  onChangeText,
  secure,
  type,
  icon,
  value,
  action
}) => (
  <View style={styles.fieldWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.heading}>{label}</Text>
    <View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={secure}
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        textContentType={type}
        value={value} />
      {icon ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={action}
          underlayColor='transparent'>
          {!secure ? <EyeHide height={30} width={30} /> : <EyeView height={30} width={30} />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: This is how I make it work by passing a parameter in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the same state variable 'secure' for both the fields. Hence toggling one field affects both.

Use different state fields for password and confirmPassword,

```js
this.state = {
  // Other fields can be the same.
  passwordSecure: true,
  confirmPasswordSecure: true
}
```

Either have 2 separate toggle handlers,

```js
togglePassword = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ passwordSecure: !prevState.passwordSecure }))
  }

toggleConfirmPassword = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ confirmPasswordSecure: !prevState.confirmPasswordSecure})
}
```

or, use a single toggle handler and use the event object to identify which field is being clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But don't want to create states and function for every field. Can you tell me how can I use an event object with the prevstate?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

I have updated the answer to work with the common field for both inputs:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
  
    super(props);
    
      this.state = {
        secure: true,
        showConfirmPwd: false,
        showPwd: false
      }
      
      this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this) 
  }

  
  handleItemClick(name){
 
    switch(name){
    
      case 'pwd':
      this.setState({showPwd: !this.state.showPwd});
      break;

      case 'confirmPwd':
      this.setState({showConfirmPwd: !this.state.showConfirmPwd});
      break;

      default:
      return;
      
     }
  }

  render(){
    
    let { secure, showConfirmPwd, showPwd } = this.state;

    return(
    
      <div>      
        <Field handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick} showPwd={showPwd} switchKey="pwd" placeholder="password" />
        <Field handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick} switchKey="confirmPwd" showConfirmPwd={showConfirmPwd} placeholder="confirm password" />
     </div>
     
    )
  }
}

const Field = ({ showPwd, showConfirmPwd, placeholder, handleItemClick, switchKey }) => {
  return(
  
    <div>
      
      <input type={(showConfirmPwd || showPwd)? "text": "password" } placeholder={placeholder} />
      <span onClick={() => handleItemClick(switchKey)}> eye </span>
      
    </div>
  
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I am using react native element Text Input which doesn't have a 'type' parameter. I am expecting a shorter solution with an event object.

Comment: @MonikaRangta Okay react-native TextInput is with 'textContentType' option in replacement to 'type'